A list of DSGE models written in Python
I intend this question to become a reference to people looking for DSGE models in Python, very similar to questions asking about bibliographical references on an area of macroeconomics.
The DSGE models could be in any area of macroeconomics.
It could be a good idea to separate answers by area.

Probably worth checking: https://quantecon.org/lectures/
